# How to merge list of dict based repeated array values?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm expecting to create the list3, grabbing the ids and then associate with each Task (list1) and remove the duplicite, but I'm not getting do it.

```py
list1 = [
    {"Name": "Richard", "Tasks":["Deadlifts","Jump"]},
    {"Name": "Peter", "Tasks": ["Jump", "OverHead"]},
    {"Name": "Paul", "Tasks": ["Dumbbel","Jump"]} 
]

list2 = [
    {"Id":1, "Exercise":["Deadlifts","Jump"]},
    {"Id":2, "Exercise":["Deadlifts"]},
    {"Id":3, "Exercise":["Dumbbel"]},
    {"Id":4, "Exercise":["OverHead","Jump"]},
    {"Id":5, "Exercise":["Deadlifts","Jump"]},
    {"Id":6, "Exercise":["Jump","Dumbbel","OverHead"]},
]

grabId = {}
for i in list2:
    for k in i["Exercise"]:
        grabId.setdefault(k,[]).append(i["Id"])

# {'Deadlifts': [1, 2, 5], 'Jump': [1, 4, 5, 6], 'Dumbbel': [3, 6], 'OverHead': [4, 6]}
```

What I'm expecting...

```py
list3 = [
    {"Name": "Richard", "Tasks":["Deadlifts","Jump"], "Ids":[1,2,4,5,6]},
    {"Name": "Peter", "Tasks": ["Jump", "OverHead"], "Ids":[1,3,4,5,6]},
    {"Name": "Paul", "Task": ["Dumbbel","Jump"], "Ids":[1,3,4,5,6]} 
]
```

Comment: Why are the IDs for Peter the same as for Paul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've understood your question well:

```py
list1 = [
    {"Name": "Richard", "Tasks": ["Deadlifts", "Jump"]},
    {"Name": "Peter", "Tasks": ["Jump", "OverHead"]},
    {"Name": "Paul", "Tasks": ["Dumbbel", "Jump"]},
]

list2 = [
    {"Id": 1, "Exercise": ["Deadlifts", "Jump"]},
    {"Id": 2, "Exercise": ["Deadlifts"]},
    {"Id": 3, "Exercise": ["Dumbbel"]},
    {"Id": 4, "Exercise": ["OverHead", "Jump"]},
    {"Id": 5, "Exercise": ["Deadlifts", "Jump"]},
    {"Id": 6, "Exercise": ["Jump", "Dumbbel", "OverHead"]},
]

tmp = {}
for d in list2:
    for e in d["Exercise"]:
        tmp.setdefault(e, []).append(d["Id"])

list3 = [
    {**d, "Ids": sorted(set(i for t in d["Tasks"] for i in tmp[t]))}
    for d in list1
]
print(list3)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"Name": "Richard", "Tasks": ["Deadlifts", "Jump"], "Ids": [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]},
    {"Name": "Peter", "Tasks": ["Jump", "OverHead"], "Ids": [1, 4, 5, 6]},
    {"Name": "Paul", "Tasks": ["Dumbbel", "Jump"], "Ids": [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]},
]
```

Comment: How to handle when KeyError shows up?

Comment: @Hasunohana You can use `d.get("Tasks", [])`, use `try..except`, `if..else` or just clean the data before.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes its a good idea to break the task into manageable pieces and test them first:

```
def get_ids(exercises):
    exercises = set(exercises)
    return list(set(d["Id"] for d in list2 if 
                    exercises.intersection(d["Exercise"])))

assert(get_ids(["Jump"]) == [1, 4, 5, 6])
assert(get_ids(["Deadlifts", "Jump"]) == [1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
```

Now put it all together:

```
for person in list1:
    person["Ids"] = get_ids(person["Tasks"])
print(list1)
```

```
[{'Name': 'Richard', 'Tasks': ['Deadlifts', 'Jump'], 'Ids': [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]}, {'Name': 'Peter', 'Tasks': ['Jump', 'OverHead'], 'Ids': [1, 4, 5, 6]}, {'Name': 'Paul', 'Tasks': ['Dumbbel', 'Jump'], 'Ids': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]}]
```